# Unable to read all measurements on Glucose device (Contour Plus One)

Tags: flutter, dart, bluetooth-lowenergy, flutter-dependencies

I am currently testing the **Contour Plus One** device with flutter_blue. I cannot get all the records from the device using via sample code. I have referred [GlucometerBluetoothToHealthKit](https://github.com/LiamsGitHub/GlucometerBluetoothToHealthKit) and try to run the commands

Examples of RACP commands (which are sparsely documented in the spec and that I had to discover iteratively):-

```
A) [1,1] Read all records. NO RESPONSE

B) [4,1] Number of records GETTING RESPONSE The total size

C) [1,6] Read the last record received NO RESPONSE

D) [1,5] Read first record NO RESPONSE

E) [1,3,1,45,0] Read extract from record 45 onwards NO RESPONSE
```

Please note I am getting the response when taking the live blood sample. I can see that in logs

The steps and screenshots are as follows:-

> 1. Device connected.
> 2. Expand Service 0x1808.
> 3. Press Notify option on characteristics 0x2A18.
> 4. Click Write option Characteristics 0x2A52 (With [1,1]) NO
>    OUTPUT

[image]

Well, my Glucose device is having 6 records. I am not sure what I am missing here.

Also, I have noted an interesting behavior noted here when I press the sync button on the Health2Sync Android app (A complete separate app from the play store) I am able to see the output in 0x2A18 (PFA image)

[image]

I think I am triggering the wrong command to get the values. Can someone please help with the commands to get all values? I have already referred to the following articles but nothing helped

> 1. [How to enable RACP to read all measurements on a Glucose device?
>    #652](https://github.com/Polidea/react-native-ble-plx/issues/652#)  2) [Android BLE notifications for Glucose](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24990061/android-ble-notifications-for-glucose) 3) [BLE glucose meter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60774009/ble-glucose-meter)

Comment: Did you figure out ?

Comment: @Sophia, did you get this going by any chance?